# I cannot make ajax requests with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to make comments on rails with Ajax request. I added some code for this and eventually I encountered such an error.

```
Missing partial comments/_comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/adilc/Desktop/Ruby Dersleri/Book-Sharing/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.3.4/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3.4/app/views"
```

Extracted source (around line #63):

```
<% end %>
    
<%= render @book.comments %> (ERROR IN THIS LINE)
<div class="comments"></div>
<h4 style="margin-top: 5px;" align="center"> Comments </h4>
```

My Codes;

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
    
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    
        def create
    
            if current_user
    
                @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
                @comment = @book.comments.create(comment_params)
                @comment.user_id = current_user.id
                @comment.approve = false
                @comment.save
                
    
                respond_to do |format|
                    format.js
                end
            end
    
        end
    
        def show
    
            @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    
        end
```

app/views/comments/show.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">

  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <p>
    <h4><%= @comment.book.title %> Book Comment</h4>
  </p>

  <br>

  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @comment.title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <%= @comment.body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= link_to @comment.user.username, @comment.user %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Approve It', @comment_path, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
  </p>
  <br>
```

app/views/comments/create.js.erb

```
$("#flash_notice").html("Your review is under review for approval");

$(".comments").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment))%>");
```

app/views/books/show.html.erb

```
<div class="book_info">


  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @book.title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Author:</strong>
    <%= @book.author %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Page Count:</strong>
    <%= @book.pagecount %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>User:</strong>
    <%= link_to @book.user.username, @book.user %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Tradable:</strong>
    <% if @book.tradeable %>
      Open to sharing
    <% else %>
            Not shared
    <% end %>
  </p>


  <% if @book.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book), class: 'btn btn-outline-primary', style: 'margin-bottom: 5px;' %>
  <% end %>
  <% if current_user %>
    <div class="flash_notice"></div>
    <h4> Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= form_with(model: [@book, @book.comments.build], local: false) do |form| %>

      <p>
        <%= form.label :title %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', style: 'width: 50%' %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= form.label :body %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', style: 'width: 50%' %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= form.submit %>
      </p>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>
  <h4 style="margin-top: 5px;" align="center"> Comments </h4>
  <%= render @book.comments %>
  <div class="comments"></div>
```

How can I solve this error or throw ajax differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you that you are missing the file that houses the location you referenced.

In your js

```
$(".comments").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment))%>");
```

You are not giving a location, so rails is determining it for you, based on the object class.

All partials (which are what is rendered from a js escape) will have an underscore at the start of the filename.  And since the object type is a `Comment` - its trying to find the the file

```
comments/_comment.html.erb
```

You can solve this by moving your `show.html.erb` to `_comment.html.erb`

Comment: Thank you it worked but there is a problem like this. I pull the comments in _comment.html.erb with each, but when I press show.html.erb on the screen, no matter how many comments I have, show.html.erb loops as much as the number of comments and it appears on multiple screens from one comment.

Comment: The only part that should be in the _comments really is the comment form and show.  The